# Thinkpad L450 Webcam not working

Tags: webcam, 15.04, thinkpad

I've installed ubuntu 15.04 on my new Thinkpad L450. So far everything is working. But the Webcam does not seem to work, it is not recognized, e. g. by cheese.

```
$ lsusb

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 5986:055a Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Acer device is supposed to be the webcam as far as I know....

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: This [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/hwe-next/+bug/1433906) is now fixed in Xenial / Yakkety -proposed kernel, if the verification task went well, it should be available in updates about two weeks later. I would suggest you to upgrade your system to Xenial to get it work.

Comment: I can confirm that it is fixed now. The webcam is working!

Answer (score 1):

I got this camera to work with a patch i received from the linux-uvc mailing list. 
See this thread here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/linux-uvc/mailman/message/34181466/

Comment: the patch is a bit difficult to spot within the thread - its called 'ignore_chining_errors.patch' ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this webcam is not supported yet. Here is the bug report.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-lts-utopic/+bug/1433906